# React conversion of MDN's touch event / gesture logger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, touch, gesture

Here's Mozilla's code for handling touch gestures, such as two finger pinch/zoom, etc.

https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/main/touchevents/Multi-touch_interaction.html

And here is the live demo:
https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/touchevents/Multi-touch_interaction.html
(This will only work on mobile—or at least it doesn't work on my Macbook Chrome browser.

I'm trying to replicate the same output using React. Here's what I have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TouchEventsContainer = () => {
  const [logEvents, setLogEvents] = useState(false);
  const [tpCache, setTpCache] = useState([]);
  const [logText, setLogText] = useState("");
  const [testText, setTestText] = useState("Tap Swipe");

  const enableLog = () => {
    setLogEvents(!logEvents);
    setTestText(logText);
  };
  const clearLog = () => setLogText('');

  const log = (name, ev, printTargetIds) => {
    let s = `${name}: touches = ${ev.touches.length} ; targetTouches = ${ev.targetTouches.length} ; changedTouches = ${ev.changedTouches.length}`;
    if (printTargetIds) {
      s += "";
      for (var i = 0; i < ev.targetTouches.length; i++) {
        s += `... id = ${ev.targetTouches[i].identifier} <br>`;
      }
    }
    setLogText((prevLogText) => prevLogText + s + "<br>");
  };

  const updateBackground = (ev) => {
    switch (ev.targetTouches.length) {
      case 1:
        ev.target.style.background = "yellow";
        break;
      case 2:
        ev.target.style.background = "pink";
        break;
      default:
        ev.target.style.background = "lightblue";
    }
  }

  const handlePinchZoom = (ev) => {
    if (ev.targetTouches.length === 2 && ev.changedTouches.length === 2) {
      let point1 = -1, point2 = -1;
      for (let i = 0; i < tpCache.length; i++) {
        if (tpCache[i].identifier === ev.targetTouches[0].identifier) point1 = i;
        if (tpCache[i].identifier === ev.targetTouches[1].identifier) point2 = i;
      }
      if (point1 >= 0 && point2 >= 0) {
        let diff1 = Math.abs(tpCache[point1].clientX - ev.targetTouches[0].clientX);
        let diff2 = Math.abs(tpCache[point2].clientX - ev.targetTouches[1].clientX);
        const PINCH_THRESHHOLD = ev.target.clientWidth / 10;
        if (diff1 >= PINCH_THRESHHOLD && diff2 >= PINCH_THRESHHOLD)
          ev.target.style.background = "green";
        } else {
        setTpCache([]);
       }
    }
  }

  const startHandler = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (ev.targetTouches.length === 2) {
      const newTpCache = [...tpCache];
      for (let i = 0; i < ev.targetTouches.length; i++) {
        newTpCache.push(ev.targetTouches[i]);
      }
      setTpCache(newTpCache);
    }
    if (logEvents) {
      log("touchStart", ev, true);
    }
    updateBackground(ev);
  };

  const moveHandler = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (logEvents) {
      log("touchMove", ev, false);
    }
    if (!(ev.touches.length === 2 && ev.targetTouches.length === 2)) {
      updateBackground(ev);
    }
    ev.target.style.outline = "dashed";
    handlePinchZoom(ev);
  };

  const endHandler = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (logEvents) {
      log(ev.type, ev, false);
    }
    if (ev.targetTouches.length === 0) {
      ev.target.style.background = "white";
      ev.target.style.outline = "1px solid black";
    }
  };

  const setHandlers = (name) => {
    const el = document.getElementById(name);
    el.ontouchstart = startHandler;
    el.ontouchmove = moveHandler;
    el.ontouchcancel = endHandler;
    el.ontouchend = endHandler;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setHandlers("target1");
    setHandlers("target2");
    setHandlers("target3");
    setHandlers("target4");
  }, []);

    return (
    <>
        <h1>Multi-touch interaction</h1>
        <div id="target1">{testText}</div>
        <div id="target2"> Tap, Hold or Swipe me 2</div>
        <div id="target3"> Tap, Hold or Swipe me 3</div>
        <div id="target4"> Tap, Hold or Swipe me 4</div>

        <button id="log" onClick={() => enableLog()}>Start/Stop event logging</button>
        <button id="clearlog" onClick={() => clearLog()}>Clear the log</button>
        <p></p>
        <div>{logText}</div>
    </>
    );
};

export default TouchEventsContainer;
```

I have 2 problems:

1. My log output (currently in a ) doesn't produce anything. I think it's because my string contains HTML. I tried using "dangerousInnerHTML" and some other things, but to no avail.
2. The two finger pinch-zoom (when background color turns green) doesn't seem to be detected.

What is wrong with my React conversion?

Also I'm currently rendering my TouchEventsContainer within the context of a different JS view (on my app) for testing, but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: When you are using React, using JS to add events is a BAD practice. You have all events in react as well. Your first issue is because of this only. You are referring a state variable in handlers but they are set once and it uses initial reference only. So when you change state, its still relying on previous state and works. It is not updated on state's change

Comment: Thank you Rajesh. So when I eliminated the useEffect and referenced the build in handlers as you mentioned, it worked. (Problem #1 is fixed)
```
<div id="target1" onTouchStart={startHandler} onTouchMove={moveHandler} onTouchCancel={moveHandler} onTouchEnd={endHandler}>{testText}</div>

<div id="target2" onTouchStart={startHandler} onTouchMove={moveHandler} onTouchCancel={moveHandler} onTouchEnd={endHandler}> Tap, Hold or Swipe me 2</div>
```

So then, any thoughts on Problem #2?
Also, is there any info I can read more on why doing this "setHandlers" approach doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like for Problem #2 the issue had to do with my PINCH_THRESHHOLD

When I changed it to 
const PINCH_THRESHHOLD = ev.target.clientWidth / 100;

it worked.

Why is the clientWidth different for my code than for the MDN code? I would think that the clientWidth should be the same since it's the same browser in each case, but maybe I'm misunderstanding what the clientWidth is

Edit: upon a quick search, I see that clientWidth is essentially the element's width...